# python merging dictionary of lists of lists/tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Consider 2 dictionaries,

```
d1 = {'current':    [[1369713600, 29], [1369756800, 47], [1369800000, 34]],
      'curr_total': 110,
      'past':       [[1368417600, 2], [1368460800, 70], [1368504000, 10]],
      'past_total': 82}

d2 = {'current':    [(1369713601, 23), (1369756800, 87), (1369800000, 7)],
      'curr_total': 117,
      'past':       [(1368417600, 100), (1368460800, 7), (1368504000, 9)],
      'past_total': 116}
```

- In first dict, some values are integers (totals) and others are list of lists
- In 2nd dict, some values are integers (totals) and others are list of tuples.
- In both dictionaries, there are common keys like 'current','cure_total' and as such.
- For same key in both dictionaries, first value of list/tuples can be same or otherwise.

Based on this, I need a dictionary like this.

```
f = {'current':    [[1369713600, 29], [1369713601, 23], [1369756800, 134], [1369800000, 41]],
     'curr_total': 227,
     'past':       [[1368417600, 102], [1368460800, 77], [1368504000, 19]],
     'past_total': 198}
```

My attempt to do is:

```
for i in fo,pl:             
    for j in i:             
        if total.get(j):    
            total[j] += i[j]
        else:               
            total[j] = i[j]
```

But found out that, if the first value is same, 2nd value of corresponding list and tuples are not aggregated? My way is very naive any way? Can someone suggest me more pythonic and efficient way to do this?

Comment: it looks like you consider `1369756800` a key?

Comment: @njzk2 I don't but situation is such that, if first value in the list matches, add that list's second value. Why demote this question? is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: If you look around on SO this can be answered via other similar questions.

Comment: Looks like your tuples should be dictionaries, not tuples.  There's one way to start... (A dictionary can be thought of as a specialized form of a list of tuples)

Comment: @jon_shep post an example, then.  Bad form to downvote without explicitly explaining why.

Also, his question is a bit different: he's got (oddly) nested dictionaries...

Comment: @jon_shep can you please paste a link. I looked around for 20 mins and saw some simple examples but not exactly this one. Why downvote? that seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: your inner tuples/lists should be dictionaries. that would make more sense

Comment: i'd start by adding like you already do, then a second phase with a group by on the second item of the list, then a reduce on each group.

Comment: `curr_total` and `past_total` seem redundant here: these can be obtained by adding up numbers from the lists

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl I didn't downvote, just mentioned that a simple k,v dictionary problem can be solved by using a little brain power and reverse engineering the large amount of other k,v dictionary problems... When I downvote I always use a "-1" and state a reason. So please don't point finger here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't intend to imply you were the downvoter, however a "dupe" comment is way less useful than a sampling of links.  The problem for many beginners is in finding the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning a list of list for `'current'` and `'past'`, I am using a dict here, as it is a more appropriate data structure for this case.

In case if you still want them to return a list then you can use `total['current'].items()` or `total['past'].items()`

```
from itertools import chain
d1 = {'current':    [[1369713600, 29], [1369756800, 47], [1369800000, 34]],
      'curr_total': 110,
      'past':       [[1368417600, 2], [1368460800, 70], [1368504000, 10]],
      'past_total': 82}

d2 = {'current':    [(1369713601, 23), (1369756800, 87), (1369800000, 7)],
      'curr_total': 117,
      'past':       [(1368417600, 100), (1368460800, 7), (1368504000, 9)],
      'past_total': 116}

total  = {}
for k,v in chain(d1.iteritems() ,d2.iteritems()):
    if isinstance(v, list):
        for k1, v1 in v:
            dic = total.setdefault(k,{})
            dic[k1] = dic.get(k1,0) + v1
    else:
        total[k] = total.get(k,0) + v

#convert the dicts to list
for k in total:
    if isinstance(total[k], dict):
        total[k] = total[k].items()
print total
```

**Output:**

```
{'current': [(1369713600, 29), (1369756800, 134), (1369800000, 41), (1369713601, 23)],
 'past': [(1368417600, 102), (1368460800, 77), (1368504000, 19)],
 'curr_total': 227,
 'past_total': 198
}
```

Comment: Like your approach and it works but returns dict of dict where as OP, it shall return dict of list of lists where applicable. I will need to modify the receiver of this dictionary to make this work. However, I think, based on hint from your answer, I will modify to get what I want.

Comment: @CuriousMind Using a dict of dict is an efficient approach, and as I've already mentioned if you want lists then use `total['current'].items()`.

Comment: can you convert the answer to return list of lists if don't mind.

Comment: Thank you. You are mind blowing. Appreciate your help. learned a lot from your approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in fo,pl:             
    for j in i:             
        if total.get(j):    
            total[j] += i[j]
        else:               
            total[j] = i[j]
```

is a good start, but as you pointed out, you'll end up with lists such as :

```
f['current'] = [[1369713600, 29], [1369756800, 47], [1369800000, 34], (1369713601, 23), (1369756800, 87), (1369800000, 7)]
```

such list is reduced by :

```
l = map(list, f['current'])
res = []
for k, v in groupby(sorted(l), lambda x: x[0]):
    res.append([k, sum(map(lambda x: x[1], v))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
d1 = {'current':    [[1369713600, 29], [1369756800, 47], [1369800000, 34]],
    'curr_total': 110,
    'past':       [[1368417600, 2], [1368460800, 70], [1368504000, 10]],
    'past_total': 82}

d2 = {'current':    [(1369713601, 23), (1369756800, 87), (1369800000, 7)],
    'curr_total': 117,
    'past':       [(1368417600, 100), (1368460800, 7), (1368504000, 9)],
    'past_total': 116}

def merge_dicts(d1, d2):
    d = dict()
    for key, val in d1.items():
        if key in d2:
            try:
                val1 = dict(val)
                val2 = dict(d2[key])
                d[key] = merge_dicts(val1, val2).items()
            except TypeError:
                d[key] = val + d2[key]
        else:
            d[key] = val
    return d

merge_dicts(d1, d2)
```

**Output:**

```
{'curr_total': 227,
 'current': [(1369713600, 29), (1369756800, 134), (1369800000, 41)],
 'past': [(1368417600, 102), (1368460800, 77), (1368504000, 19)],
 'past_total': 198}
```